# Вывести общее количество лайков с фреймов

Tags: php, html

На сайте висит 2 кнопки лайков с фейсбука и с вконтакте, как посчитать их общее количество и вывести в отдельное значение?

```
<div id="vk_like"><script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "mini"});
</script></div>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="/" data-layout="button_count" data action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-size="small" data-width="50" data-share="false"></div>
```

Comment: Лучше всего используйте API как посоветовал @Yury-Bakharev. Это оптимальное и правильное решение. Можете получать значения по крону ночью и писать себе в БД. Или же пользуйтесь `file_get_contents` парсите страницы и получайте количества лайков.

Answer (score 1):

Как сделать разбирая код страницы я не знаю, но вы можете воспользоваться API VK или Facebook. (likes.getList - например в VK и https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/ - Facebook)